# Angular reactive form value not modified

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms, formgroups

I've got a behavior I do not understand. I have a `formGroup` with only 4 fields, 2 being date (with date pickers) and 2 being numbers. For some reason, change in numbers input fields do not reflect on form value, but if I change one of the date value, then the input number value is set.

Below part of my component code (obviously I've got a `onSubmit()` method but not pasting it for the sake of concision):

```
const datesCoherencyValidator: ValidatorFn = (form: FormGroup) => {
  const startDate: Date = form.get('visaStart')?.value as Date;
  const endDate: Date = form.get('visaEnd')?.value as Date;
  if (startDate && endDate) {
    if (endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime() > 0) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return { dateRange: true };
    }
  }
  return { noDate: true };
};

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-visa',
  templateUrl: './add-visa.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-visa.component.scss']
})
export class AddVisaComponent implements OnInit {
  public visaCreationForm: FormGroup;
  private readonly today = new Date();
  public readonly defaultStartDate = new Date(
    this.today.getFullYear(),
    this.today.getMonth(),
    1
  );
  public readonly defaultEndDate = new Date(
    this.today.getFullYear(),
    this.today.getMonth(),
    15
  );

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.visaCreationForm = this.fb.group(
      {
        visaStart: [
          this.defaultStartDate,
          {
            validators: [Validators.required],
            updateOn: 'blur'
          }
        ],
        visaEnd: [
          this.defaultEndDate,
          {
            validators: [Validators.required],
            updateOn: 'blur'
          }
        ],
        visaYear: [
          this.today.getFullYear(),
          { validators: [Validators.required], updateOn: 'blur' }
        ],
        visaMonth: [
          this.today.getMonth() + 1,
          {
            validators: [
              Validators.required,
              Validators.min(1),
              Validators.max(12)
            ],
            updateOn: 'blur'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        validators: [datesCoherencyValidator],
        updateOn: 'submit'
      }
    );
  }
```

For debug purpose I added this method:

```
  public showValues(): void {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.visaCreationForm.value));
  }
```

In my template, the form is as below:

```
<form id="visaCreationForm" (ngSubmit)="visaCreationForm.valid && onSubmit()" [formGroup]="visaCreationForm" >
      <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="medium">
        <mat-label>Start Date</mat-label>
        <input matInput #visaStart (click)="visaStartDatePicker.open()" [matDatepicker]="visaStartDatePicker"
          formControlName="visaStart" required />
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="visaStartDatePicker">
          <mat-datepicker [startAt]="defaultStartDate" #visaStartDatePicker></mat-datepicker>
        </mat-datepicker-toggle>
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="medium">
        <mat-label>End Date</mat-label>
        <input matInput #visaEnd (click)="visaEndDatePicker.open()" [matDatepicker]="visaEndDatePicker"
          formControlName="visaEnd" required />
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="visaEndDatePicker">
          <mat-datepicker [startAt]="defaultEndDate" #visaEndDatePicker></mat-datepicker>
        </mat-datepicker-toggle>
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="medium">
        <mat-label>Year</mat-label>
        <input matInput #visaYear formControlName="visaYear" type="number" required (change)="showValues()" />
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="medium">
        <mat-label>Month</mat-label>
        <input matInput #visaMonth type="number" formControlName="visaMonth" min="1" max="12" required (change)="showValues()" />
      </mat-form-field>
    </form>
```

Some consol output to show my "problem", as said, first two actions consists in changing the year field value (which triggers the `showValues()`) with down arrows (thus 2 actions, 2 changes), then I pick a date for the start, and the new value for the year finally shows:

```
vvvvvvvvv Changed Year input field to 2019 --> not showing ... vvvvvvvvvvv
14:56:32.611 add-visa.component.ts:127 {"visaStart":"2021-10-31T23:00:00.000Z","visaEnd":"2021-11-14T23:00:00.000Z","visaYear":2021,"visaMonth":11}
14:56:32.611 add-visa.component.ts:127 {"visaStart":"2021-10-31T23:00:00.000Z","visaEnd":"2021-11-14T23:00:00.000Z","visaYear":2021,"visaMonth":11}
vvvvvvvvv Changed Start Year then month --> now years shows ô_O but not the new Month value -_- vvvvvvvvvvv
14:56:39.516 add-visa.component.ts:127 {"visaStart":"2021-11-16T23:00:00.000Z","visaEnd":"2021-11-14T23:00:00.000Z","visaYear":2019,"visaMonth":11}
```

I'm definitely missing something here but I do not know what. I've removed the formGroup validators with the same behavior, removed the formControls validators without any effect as well, it's as if I needed to pick a date after changing year and/or month for these values to apply. Needless to say this is not what I expect!

If you got any idea they'll be more than welcome, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, this was due to the `updateOn` on the `formgroup` validator side:

```
{
    validators: [datesCoherencyValidator],
    updateOn: 'submit'
}
```

For some reason, the `datepicker` was bypassing this; I do not know why, but when I removed that, all of my controls were live updating again. I'm leaving this in case someone made the same mistake.

Based on [the documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#updateOn), I first thought this was a way to make sure to provide the parent `formgroup` as a validator trigger, but I guess it is applying the 'submit' hook to all `formControls` of my group instead, which explains why I wasn't seeing the value change at my `(onChange)`.